How can I enable @Configuration POJO's to be loaded from a file on the classpath, but outside of a normal spring boot context?
I'm wanting to load up properties on an object, but outside of a spring boot context (legacy code that isn't using spring boot).  i.e: instantiate an object, and fill it's properties from application.yml, which is on the classpath.
The POJO itself is from ORS, like so:
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(
    prefix = "ors.endpoints"
)
public class EndpointsProperties {
    private EndpointDefaultProperties defaults;
    private EndpointRoutingProperties routing;
    private EndpointMatrixProperties matrix;
    private EndpointIsochronesProperties isochrones;
    private EndpointSnapProperties snap;

From what I can tell, I need to add spring boots ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.
I've tried doing this, but I get:

Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': Cannot invoke "org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry.containsBeanDefinition(String)" because "beanDefinitionRegistry" is null

when I refresh() the context. Complete code is:
public static EndpointsProperties makeDefaultEndpointPropertiesBean() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

        context.register(EndpointsProperties.class);

        ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor postProcessor = new ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor();
        postProcessor.setApplicationContext(context);
        context.getBeanFactory().addBeanPostProcessor(postProcessor);

        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setProperties(Objects.requireNonNull(yaml.getObject()));
        context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);


        context.refresh();

        try {
            postProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        EndpointsProperties endpointsProperties = context.getBean(EndpointsProperties.class);
        return endpointsProperties;
    }

I'm guessing that it's because afterPropertiesSet() hasn't been called on ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.  But I can't do that before the refresh().
I don't know enough about spring boot (only been using it 1 day) to know how to fix this.
Any tips?
